# Getting Warning: Cannot update during an existing state transition inside render

Tags: reactjs, react-native, setstate

There are lots of question around this warning already, but I can't understand why my code is causing this warning. Just trying a basic login screen to get mobile no. and if valid no., action to send otp is dispatched and user is navigated to another screen.
Commented out few `setState` lines but still getting this warning. Any help is appreciated.
Code:

```
class Login extends Component{
state = {
   phone: '',
   validNumber: ''
 }

 handlePhoneChange(value) {
    var regex = /^0[9786]{1}[0-9]{9}/;   
    this.setState({phone: value, validNumber: ''})  
    if(regex.test(value))
    {
      //this.setState({validNumber: 'true'})
       this.props.sendOtp(value)
     }
     else if(value.length == 11) 
    {
      //    this.setState({validNumber: 'false'})
        } 
    }

    onLoginSuccess(){
        const {loginSuccess} = this.props;
        if(loginSuccess != null && loginSuccess != undefined)
        {
            if(loginSuccess === 'YES')
            {
               // this.resetValues()
                this.props.navigation.navigate('Otp')
            }
        }
    }

    resetValues() {
        this.props.resetResponse()
        // this.setState({
        //      phone: '', 
        //     validNumber: ''
        // });
    }

    render(){
        return (
        <View style={{ flex: 1}} >
                <Input 
                placeholder='Enter Mobile Number'
                keyboardType = 'phone-pad' 
                value = {this.state.phone}
                onChangeText = { (value) => { this.handlePhoneChange(value.replace(/\D/g,'')) } }
                inputStyle = {{fontSize: 14}}
                maxLength = {11}
                rightIcon = { this.state.validNumber === 'true'? 
                            <CustomIcon name = 'Tick' size={25} color = 'green'/> : null}
                errorMessage = {this.state.validNumber === 'false'? 'Please enter a valid number' : ''}
                />
                {this.onLoginSuccess()}
        </View>
        )
    }
}
```

UPDATE:
Warning msg is as follows

```
  ERROR    Warning: Cannot update during an existing state transition (such as within `render`). Render methods should be a pure function of props and state.
    in LoginScreen (created by ConnectFunction)
    in ConnectFunction (created by SceneView)
    in SceneView (created by CardContainer)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (created by CardContainer)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (created by CardContainer)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (created by ForwardRef(CardSheet))
    in ForwardRef(CardSheet) (created by Card)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at createAnimatedComponent.js:165)
    in AnimatedComponent (at createAnimatedComponent.js:215)
    in ForwardRef(AnimatedComponentWrapper) (created by PanGestureHandler)
    in PanGestureHandler (created by PanGestureHandler)
    in PanGestureHandler (created by Card)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at createAnimatedComponent.js:165)
    in AnimatedComponent (at createAnimatedComponent.js:215)
    in ForwardRef(AnimatedComponentWrapper) (created by Card)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (created by Card)
    in Card (created by CardContainer)
    in CardContainer (created by CardStack)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (created by MaybeScreen)
    in MaybeScreen (created by CardStack)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (created by MaybeScreenContainer)
    in MaybeScreenContainer (created by CardStack)
    in CardStack (created by Context.Consumer)
    in KeyboardManager (created by Context.Consumer)
    in RNCSafeAreaProvider (at SafeAreaContext.tsx:74)
    in SafeAreaProvider (created by Context.Consumer)
    in SafeAreaProviderCompat (created by StackView)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (created by StackView)
    in StackView (created by StackView)
    in StackView
    in Unknown (created by Navigator)
    in Navigator (created by NavigationContainer)
    in NavigationContainer (at App.js:22)
    in Provider (at App.js:21)
    in App (at renderApplication.js:45)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at AppContainer.js:106)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at AppContainer.js:132)
    in AppContainer (at renderApplication.js:39)
```

Comment: Can you confirm which line is causing the warning to be triggered?

Comment: I am new to react and hence unable to see which line causes this warning.Let me edit and update my warning

Comment: Alright, let's try it another way. What happens if you comment out the `this.onLoginSuccess()` inside your return statement? I know that your code won't redirect you, but does the warning go away?

Comment: Yes, the warning goes away

Comment: I've added an answer. Please let me know if that solves your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it seems that your problem lies in your fn call.
Although I don't know at which point you receive your login prop, nevertheless, yo should do something as follows.

1. Remove your function call from the return.

The problem with that is that whenever React rerenders your component, your function is going to be called. One way this is a problem, that I can imagine, is that if you're already navigating away from the component, so this function was called, but this component was not removed from the stack and so it tries to rerender during your navigation event.
This is not the exact reason of your problem, but it's a possible trigger for this kind of warning.

2. Move your navigation inside `componentDidUpdate`.

This way your function will be called only once, when your props have changed, and navigation won't happen during the render phase, as this lifecycle method is called after your component renders.

```
class Login extends Component{
state = {
   phone: '',
   validNumber: ''
 }

 componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
   if (!prevProps.loginSuccess && this.props.loginSuccess === "YES") {
     this.props.navigation.navigate('Otp')
   }
 }

    render(){
        return (
        <View style={{ flex: 1}} >
                <Input 
                placeholder='Enter Mobile Number'
                keyboardType = 'phone-pad' 
                value = {this.state.phone}
                onChangeText = { (value) => { this.handlePhoneChange(value.replace(/\D/g,'')) } }
                inputStyle = {{fontSize: 14}}
                maxLength = {11}
                rightIcon = { this.state.validNumber === 'true'? 
                            <CustomIcon name = 'Tick' size={25} color = 'green'/> : null}
                errorMessage = {this.state.validNumber === 'false'? 'Please enter a valid number' : ''}
                />
        </View>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for explaining that you cannot navigate away from the component while it is rendering, at least not in a procedural fashion. You can either do it in componentDidUpdate or useEffect after the rendering is done OR you can possibly do it in the rendering logic by using something like react router's Redirect component in a declarative fashion (which is what I did).